# How to drag-n-drop TableItem from one component to another in material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-dnd

The problem is I have to drag a ListItem from One List component to another. I don't know How can I achieve it in Material UI.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show us what you tried and ask about a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Material UI Drag and Drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) module provide you with a way to easily and declaratively create drag-and-drop interfaces, with support for free dragging, sorting within a list, transferring items between lists, animations, touch devices, custom drag handles, previews, and placeholders, in addition to horizontal lists and locking along an axis.

Here's a very simple example with two List component. I recommend you to play around in this [example link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jrlygyngboj?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts).

HTML

```
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>To do</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-container">
  <h2>Done</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
todo = [
    'Get to work',
    'Pick up groceries',
    'Go home',
    'Fall asleep'
  ];

  done = [
    'Get up',
    'Brush teeth',
    'Take a shower',
    'Check e-mail',
    'Walk dog'
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
```